# Display data which comes from a Golang controller

Tags: html, go

I am new to Go language. I work on a Basic MVC Web Application in Go (josephspurrier's project on https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/README.md). I have a controller which consumes a REST web service:

```
func InfoGET(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     var infos []model.Info
     //call web service and get data
     infos, err := ws.GetAllInfos("tho")
     if(err != nil) {
      log.Println(err)
     }
     v := view.New(r)
     v.Name = "infos/info"
     v.Render(w)
}
```

I want to display the data I have gotten thanks to the webservice (displaying them in a datatable would be great I think). What do I have to write in my .tmpl file in order to achieve this?

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Comment: None. I am using josephspurrier's project (https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example:

Controller:
https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/vendor/app/controller/notepad.go

View: 
https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/template/notepad/read.tmpl

```
// This adds your collection to the template
v.Vars["infos"] = infos
```

In your template you iterate over your infos using range:

```
{{range $info := .infos}}
```

Inside range you access specific properties using {{.PropertyName}}

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to do that

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If it's a correct answer, please mark it, so others could use it.

Comment: It seems that I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.. I would really like to mark your answer as a correct answser but it seems I can't..

Comment: I have marked your answer as a correct answser, thank you again